# Deleting Several Rows with a condition

Tags: c#, sql

Hello trying to delete several rows of the table according to a condition, however i need some help with it, basically i want to delete all rows, while the condition is true and then stop and leave the rest untouched.

EDIT: Regarding the comments i apologize, im fairly new to programming, sorry if not doing things correctly im new to this website as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string varsql2check = ""; 
   do{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd");
        conn.Open();
        string varsql = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE 'tipodoc' ='FSS' and 'FP' "; //sql query

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(varsql, conn);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     } while(varsql2check = "SELECT * from wgcdoccab where 'tipodoc' !='FSS' and !='FP'  and contribuinte !='999999990' and  datadoc != CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120);");

        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: You didn't indicate if something went wrong. Did you get an error?

Comment: You have so many wrong in your code. Your queries won't _even_ work. Have you ever read the book about C# and ADO.NET first?

Comment: You are using single quotes around column names.  I consider this a typographic error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: No i havent, im new to c# programming in general thats why i was wondering if anyone could explain how to do this proper. Sorry if the question is that bad.

Comment: Why not do the whole loop inside SQL it will be allot more performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool check = true;
     do
     {
          string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
          string queryString = string.Empty;
          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
          {
               connection.Open();
               queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE 'tipodoc' ='FSS' and 'FP' ";
               SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
               command.Connection.Open();
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "SELECT * from wgcdoccab where 'tipodoc' !='FSS' and !='FP'  and contribuinte !='999999990' and  datadoc != CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120)";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        check = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
           }          
      } 
      while (check);
}
```

Generally what I have done by editing your code is:

1. Add the `using` statement in order to release the resources from the established connections.
2. You should be using the returned types from the exeqution of the queries. The `ExecuteNonQuery()` will return the numbers of rows affected, in our case we are particularly interested in the rows returned from the select statement after the delete query. We create a reader and depending of the number of rows, in our case we are only interested if there are rows or no, branch accoringly. If we get no rows from the select (everything is deleted) we just continue, if we get nothing (`reader.HasRows` returns false) we repeat the delete query and check again.
   Simple as that.

Comment: Don't dump fixed code. Explain what error there was and how you solved it.

Comment: Yes please, if you could explain how you solve, walking me trough the solution would help me learn a lot, as i said im new to the programming scene and apologise if the question is put wrong aswell.

Comment: I added some comments to what my proposed solution is trying to achieve. Hope you find it clear enough. Did you understand it LesterNotTheMolestor?

Comment: Ok i understand it better now, thank you sir, just one more thing, this will stop deleting as soon as that sql condition isnt met anymore correct?

Comment: It will stop deleting if the select statement returns nothing.

Comment: I see, one more thing and sorry for bothering with my curiosity, but if we change the select the delete query would act differently according to those changes?

Comment: What do you mean? In general, what the code piece does is: perform delete, check if everything we wanted deleted is successfully deleted and if not - delete again if yes - continue. You can use it for any pair of queries that you want to perform the described behaviour.

Comment: You answered my question, thank you so much! This will help out a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help, I have had a bit of a first hand experience with OLEDB and WinForms, which is similar. Maybe I would add my database communication class and object loader class in codeproject, it might be interesting to beginners.